# OS X restarts every app when waking up

Tags: macbook-pro, macos, restart

When my MacBook Pro (late-2013, Mavericks) wakes up, it restarts all apps after a few seconds. After a wake up, firstly I see all apps running normal then all apps begin restarting. I think I accidentally changed a preference but I can't find it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At last I've found the solution.

When I was watching a movie I saw that message "Are you sure you want to quit all applications and log out now?" It was all about a "Security and Privacy" preference that quits all application and logout. I found the solution on [Apple Support Communities](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/4459451?tstart=0). Here is the solution:

Open the "System Preferences". In the "Security and Privacy" preference pane click the "Advanced..." button and uncheck "Logout after XX minutes of inactivity".

Answer (score 1):

I presume you're talking about Resume, a feature that will cause apps that were left open when you logged out to open again when you login.

From your explanation, I presume you see a window of an app, but then it will fade out and appear to 'restart' — in actuality the app hasn't loaded once yet, and is loading, not restarting.

You can stop Resume by unchecking the *Reopen windows when logging back in* option in a log out or shutdown dialog.

Comment: The problem is, this is happening when I close the lid or when macbook becomes idle. In other words, I don't see a 'Reopen windows when logging back in' option, because I don't shut the computer down. Also, I didn't have this problem for over a month, since I bought the macbook - except last 2 days.

Answer (score -1):

This might be due to a bug in OS X Mavericks with no permanent solution so far. A temporary solution might be given here (at least worked for me);https://discussions.apple.com/message/23638089#23638089#23638089

Comment: Please write down the steps on how to fix it here.